# ethtool Says Speed: 1000Mb/s, So Why, ipref3 Not Exceeding 9M4b/s

Tags: gigabit-ethernet

I am currently attemping to run iperf3 between two 1000Mb capable ethernet devices, a Raspberry Pi 4 running OSMC (a Debian based Media Server distro) and a Dell XPS 15 laptop running Ubuntu.

The devices are connected to a Gigabit switch using cat 6 cables.

On both devices, running this command:

`ethtool eth0 | grep Speed`

Returns:

`Speed: 1000Mb/s`

However, iperf3 is only returning results of about 94Mb/s

I have tried changing the cables and the switch, didn't help.
I even tried this cmd:

`ethtool -s enxe4b97ac6101b speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off`

Which I rolled back as it actually slowed the speed down to about 75Mb/s.

Any suggestions how I can increase the speed?

Thank you

BrettSh

Answer (score 1):

Well... seems the issue is I was swapping out the wrong cables.

In other words, I'm an idiot who needs to label his home Ethernet cables.

Comment: While you are at it, get rid of "economy" two-pair (four-wire) cables. They're nothing but trouble.

Comment: Thanks @Zac67. In fact, that _was_ the problem. I inspected all the patch cables in my home network to ensure they were cat 5e or cat 6 and I found a crappy 2 pair cable. It went straight in the bin.